# setMovementMethod not defined?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Can anyone help? Im trying to get my android screen to automatically scroll downwards as more text is added to the TextView. Here is my code:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace GameEngine
{
    [Activity(Label = "nameScreen")]
    public class nameScreen : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.enterName); 

            TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text);

            tv.MovementMethod = new Android.Text.Method.ScrollingMovementMethod();

            FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text).Text = "Hi";

            Button send = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.send);

            tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

The tv.setMovementMethod at the bottom results:

```
'TextView' does not contain a definition for 'setMovementMethod' 
and no extension method 'setMovementMethod' accepting a first 
argument of type 'Textview' could be found (are you missing a 
using directive or and assembly reference?)
```

This is in Xamarin, in C#.

AXML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      android:text="Text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
      android:layout_height="455.5dp"
      android:id="@+id/Text"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
  <EditText
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/nameTB" />
  <Button
      android:text="Send"
      android:layout_width="379.5dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: According to TextView Class Documentation there is no method Called setMovementMethod, there is only a property called MovementMethod which is of Type IMovementMethod.  Here is TextView Class  Docs, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.TextView/

Comment: You've already used the correct approach in your example above (`tv.MovementMethod = ...`). Use the MovementMethod property to set and get values. There is no setMovementMethod method.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html ??

Comment: so, why does it not scroll automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, set* and get* methods in Java are mapped as standard C# properties with getters and setters.  So `setMovementMethod` and `getMovementMethod` would both be exposed as a `MovementMethod` property.

Comment: OK, sorry, i'm fairly new at the language. so how would i get it to scroll my window automatically?

Answer (score 1):

In C# you should do that following way

```
yourTextView.MovementMethod = new ScrollingMovementMethod() ;
```